# Constructing real exponents and related properties using solely $\lim_{n\to\infty }\left( 1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right) ^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function, exponentiation, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to define $x^y$ for real $x$ and $y$, and also prove its related properties. The tools I have are

- the definition $$e := \lim _{n\to\infty }\left( 1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right) ^{n}$$where $n \in \mathbb{N}$
- Arithmetic operations over real numbers
- Exponentiation to powers of rational numbers
- Any other lemmas and theorems without involving $e^x$ or $\ln x$

I would like to generalize this definition to:
$$ e^x := \lim _{n\to\infty }\left( 1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right) ^{n}$$for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and then define $\ln x$ and $x^y := e^{y\ln x}$ so that I can prove $\dfrac{d}{dx}e^x = e^x$ and other properties.
But first I have to show properties of indices like $$e^{x + y} = e^x e^y$$
for real $x$ and $y$.

In this case, using the definition for both $e^x$ and $e^y$ would yield
$$e^x e^y = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( 1+\dfrac{x+y}{n}+\dfrac{xy}{n^{2}}\right) ^{n}$$
How do I prove its equivalence to $\lim _{n\to\infty }\left( 1+\dfrac{x+y}{n}\right) ^{n}$ using only the tools mentioned above? Or, is there any better approaches for this property?

Comment: **Hint** $:$ Try to show that if $x_n \to x$ then $\left (1 + \frac {x_n} {n} \right )^{n} \to e^{x}.$ In your case $x_n = x + y + \frac {xy} {n} \to x + y$ as $n \to \infty.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Binomial Theorem. I'll let $1+\frac{x+y}{n}=a$, and $xy=b$.

$$a^n \le (a+\frac{b}{n^2})^n = \sum_{r=0}^n(\frac{b}{n^2})^r{a^{n-r}}_nC_r \le a^n+\sum_{r=1}^n{(\frac{b}{n^2})}^r{a^{n-r}}n^r = a^n+\sum_{r=1}^nb^r{a^{n-r}}n^{-r}$$
For sufficiently large $n$,   $b^r{a^{n-r}}n^{-r} (0<r\le n)$ is ignorable.

So, following expression is reasonable.
$$e^{x+y} = \lim _{n\to\infty }\left( 1+\dfrac{x+y}{n}\right) ^{n} = \lim _{n\to\infty }a^n = \lim _{n\to\infty }\left( a+\frac{b}{n^2}\right) ^{n} = \lim _{n\to\infty }\left( 1+\dfrac{x+y}{n}+\dfrac{xy}{n^2}\right) ^{n} = \lim _{n\to\infty }\left( 1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right) ^{n}\lim _{n\to\infty }\left( 1+\dfrac{y}{n}\right)^n = e^xe^y.$$